# Splash screen in apache cordova is not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, web-config, config, visual-studio-cordova

I'm working on apache cordova 3.0.0. I've been through the splash screens and icons document of the apache cordova documentation.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

I've implemented the splash screen in my project. But unfortunately it is not working.

Here is what I've done.

Step 1 :

Added the splash screen plugin to the project.

Step 2 :

I've added the following code to config.xml in my project.

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

<platform name="android">
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" platform="Android" density="land-hdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" platform="Android" density="land-ldpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" platform="Android" density="land-mdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" platform="Android" density="land-xhdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" platform="Android" density="port-hdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" platform="Android" density="port-ldpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" platform="Android" density="port-mdpi" />
<splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" platform="Android" density="port-xhdpi" />
</platform>
```

Could someone help me out if I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: start by updating to latest version of cordova, cordova 3.0.0 apps won't be approved on google play or app store

Answer (score 0):

The code above is correct and the process followed is correct.

Here are the points I observed and to be noted while working with splash screens in apache cordova.

- It is not working in ripple simulator, but when packaged into an .apk
  file, it is working fine on device.
- The splash image should be in
  .png format, otherwise it raises compilation errors while debugging in device mode saying, "image is not
  in .png format".